# Google Tracking & Magento Drop down Navigation

Tags: magento-enterprise, navigation, dropdown-attribute, header, category-tree

I'm trying to track click events in our 2 level drop down category navigation menu - located in the header.

All I'm trying to do is add some attributes to the `<a href>` tags but this is proving to be harder than it sounds. I can't figure out where the `$_menu` variable referenced in `topmenu.phtml` is coming from. (any ideas?) I've found 2 solutions to the this problem that only seem OK and don't think either is best practice.

### Option 1

Use an observer to intercept and modify the HTML.. This is roughly what the Anowave Tag Manager Module does.

### Option 2

[Use this example](http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/generate-magento-top-menu-navigation-html-menu-this-gethtml-level-top/) to create a fully custom top menu.. which exactly what's there already with some extra `<a href>` attributes.

### Thoughts

Option 2 requires create pretty redundant code because whatever is there is 99.9% good.. I'm just trying to include an attribute like `data-value='category name'` etc.

## ANSWER NOTES

Both @sander & @denisa posted answers that solved my problem. However, as @denisa mentioned, you need to know if you're using using the newer RWD template or the older template. I was using a newer install of Magento but and Non-RWD template. Once you know this, use either @denisa's answer or @sander's

Comment: $_menu is generated by app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

Comment: @ddavidn, it appears you're right. Can you comment on the best way to integrate a new attribute or two, or even a JS onClick() into the menu items?

Comment: Justin, I'm going to leave that to an expert. ;)

Comment: @ddavidn .. sounds good. Definitely seems like something more than a few us should be implementing.

Comment: @ddavidn That's the old navigation menu. The new one (1.6 or 1.7 and later) it is the [Top Menu](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu/Renderer.php).

Comment: @Melvyn is right, sorry.

Comment: I'm working on this with that suggestion.. I'm on a latest release so the 1.7+ solution would apply to my case.. Makes sense since the original file @ddavidn mentioned didn't work.

Comment: And while it's still not what you'd call a template, the actual rendering is now optionally done since i a template file. See [here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't extend from rwd theme, renderer.phtml won't be rendered if you will add it in your custom theme. 
I would do something like that: extend `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` and modify `protected function _getHtml` with my code. You will see there `$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'` - that's the place where you have to add you own code.

Comment: I created a module to extend the Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu [`app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`]. Worked perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding extra data can be done in the template file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml` or whatever template you're using.

On line 54 you'll find the following line

```
$html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';
```

Change that to, for example

```
$html .= '<a data-value="'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';
```

Comment: the /rwd/default directory is new to me.. IS this something we should we extend into our custom template?? IF that's the case. maybe my theme is already extending it? so close I can feel but it's not quite working yet.

Comment: might be. RWD was introduced in 1.9(?) as the default theme but the file should be the same in any theme falling back to `base/default`

Comment: It isn't. It's specific to rwd. I'm guessing because only the top level is rendered I the rwd theme they have split it it, but did not want to cause issues with legacy templates.

Comment: Just to clarify.. should I create my own `app/design/frontend/[theme]/[folder]/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml` to edit instead of editing that directly?

Comment: Justin, renderer.phtml won't be rendered if you will add it in your custom theme since you don't extend from rwd. 
I would do something like that: extend Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu and modify protected function _getHtml with my code. You will see there $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' - that's the place where you have to add you own code.

Comment: @Denisa great answer Denisa. Add it as an official answer. You'll have my upvote